# Conversion Formula for Yaw-Pitch-Roll from Raw 9-D0F IMU Values (Gyroscope, Accelerometer, Magnetometer)

Tags: python, quaternions, euler-angles, sensor-fusion, imu

I am getting raw values from a **9 DoF IMU Sensor** (MPU9250), the values contain **Gyroscope(Gx,Gy,Gz), Accelerometer(Ax,Ay,Az)**, and **Magnetometer(Mx,My,Mz)**.

I wish to get **Yaw, Pitch and Roll** from these values on Python. Can someone kindly share a conversion formula from where I can convert these raw sensor values into Yaw-Pitch-Roll (Euler Angles)? The ones I'm finding uses rotation matrices which is irrelevant to my problem.

Furthermore, what is the conversion formula for getting **Quaternions** from these IMU values?

Any help, either in the form of formulas, reference to a source, or code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this question on the Engineering Stack Exchange: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/calculating-pitch-yaw-and-roll-from-mag-acc-and-gyro-data. The code in the most voted answer is not in Python but looks easily convertable.